# creating a query with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a database, reported very bad, however I have to do a query like this: "Select from cd.descrizione reparticolo ra, coloridescr cd = WHERE cd.colori_id ra.colori_id and cd.mercati_id = 2 and ra.codice = 345475 ";

PS: The two tables are not related, and I have already created the mapping of the two tables, with no report, because of colori_id reparticolo is not the primary key and I can not create it.
Can someone tell me how can we do with NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a unique key from a subset of columns a [Composite Key](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx) approach might work for you.

If you see a chance to clean up the data that would be ideal of course.  Being without primary keys is not going to be easy, even without an ORM :)